# how to implement user group type security with Firestore (e.g. a shared todo list)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

What would be the best practice approach to implement security groups in Firestore for mobile apps (in this case react-native which effectively uses the "Web" interfaces).  To give a more specific example:

- Users using a mobile app with ability to "share" data (e.g. todo list) that is stored in Firestore [built using "Web" interface]
- Aim for very low friction approach.  Ideally starts with primary user have used the app using "Anonymous" authentication approach
- Then user wants to "share" the data (e.g. todo list) with others securely

My question is really how do you implement the above in general, but covering aspects such as

- Q1 - In terms of user experience approach what do you ask / get the user to do here?  Build this into the app code?
- Q2 - How do you structure the Firestore database to handle this?  i.e. what would the structure look like - perhaps all data is just under Primary user UID
- Q3 - How do you construct the Firestore rules to protect it?  e.g. how do you do a "user-in-group" type check here?  example?
- Q4 - What would the application code look like for:

  - creating the user security group when the primary user hits "share"
  - adding users to the group?
  - accessing the data?

Overall keen to understand the lowest friction approach to having a user securely (on mobile app with firestore "web" sdk, i.e. react-native wrapper) share his data (e.g. todo list) to other people he/she specifically selects/approves somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For posterity, this has been answered on the [google-cloud-firestore-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss) group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/KEs4is11LXc/xs2zIvQmCQAJ

TL;DR:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /lists/{listId} {
      // step 1
      allow create: if request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
      // step 3
      allow get: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/lists/$(listId)/users/$(request.auth.uid));
      match /users/{userId} {
        // step 2
        allow create: if request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/lists/$(listId)).data.owner;
      }
    }
  }
}
```